# Examples of neat and tidy PCB layout?

Tags: pcb, layout

I have gotten to the stage where I am going to be laying out my board, there are Lots of capacitors, other components, etc, etc.

Where can I find a good solid example of neat and tidy layout of moderately populated boards?

Comment: It depends on how many layers you want to have and how many different parts you want to get on the board and what you want to pay for it. If you are a beginner you can find many stuff in the forum of Eagle pcb.

Comment: Have you tried Google? =P

Comment: Neat and tidy will have different meanings for different applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always thought the neatest analog layouts were done by the Japanese by hand with smooth traces such as in Hitachi and Panasonic boards.

Then for Logic with 1 IC/sq.in with high interconnect signal density on 2 layers using orthogonal trace directions on each side for the layout. this is how I did it in the mid-70's with 50 IC's on a small board.

Autorouters are fun but you get what you pay for....

Nothing beats acquiring all the skills necessary for DFM and DFT up front. There are hundreds of rules and some learning curve.

Here's a free [**download**](http://www.epectec.com/downloads/Top-10-Circuit-Board-Design-Checks.pdf) for Layout practices to avoid. FWIW it's not the best example just 1 of many many out there.

IMHO these are examples of a "neat" layout.  (hint) look around , the answers are out there but learn the DFM rules and Supplier capabilities track/gap/microvias
[image]
[image]
[image]
Above example of 2 layer orthogonal track rules for each side, which may need a shielded box without a ground plane.
[**More simple layout ideas**](http://www.robotroom.com/PCB-Layout-Tips.html)

Comment: While I agree with the design checks in that epectec document, the author needs to chill out a bit and stop looking in the mirror so much.

Comment: agreed  IPC $pec$ are the better choice  it was just a 1 second search